# S3 versioning: only copy files if they are new or changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm running a cron job in a EC2 instance that backups a database dump and a folder (with files and subfolders) in a S3 bucket.

I only want to backup new and modified files in order to save costs. Is this possible?

I'm currently using aws cp, maybe there is an argument or another command?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aws s3 sync` instead of `aws s3 cp` and it will do this automatically for you.